# как добработать DateAdapter для jaxb парсинга дат?

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, simpledateformat

Как преобразовать входную дату **2019-03-04T18:55:05.591+03:00** в timestamp для сохранения в базу oracle?

Я использую simpleDateFormat чтобы распарсить дату  **2019-03-04T18:55:05.591+03:00** и получить Date.

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.format(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.parse(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Но, есть случай когда присылают дату без указания милисекунд и я получаю ошибку парсинга.  **2019-03-04T18:55:05+03:00**

Как этого можно избежать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.format(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) {
        return Date.from(java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(v).toInstant());
    }
}
```

Я бы предложил такое решение. На мой взгляд это проще, чем указывать 2 формата...

Answer (score 0):

Как дополнительный вариант решения, это написать утилитарный метод, который будет подбирать нужный шаблон:

```
 private static final List<SimpleDateFormat> dateFormats = Arrays.asList(
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"),
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
    );



public static Date parseToDate(String input) {
        if (input != null) {
            for (SimpleDateFormat dateFormat : dateFormats) {
                try {
                    return dateFormat.parse(input);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



 public static Timestamp parseToTimestamp(String input) {
    if (input != null) {
        for (SimpleDateFormat dateFormat : dateFormats) {
            try {
                Date date = dateFormat.parse(input);
                return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```